# Angular 4 project not working in Fire Fox & Safari

Tags: angular

I have run my project in Chrome where it successfully runs but i have run 
 the project in Firefox which shows error.

[this type of error display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYRtX.png)

I have run project in fire fox and login not work they show error like

Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost/Invitation/code. (Reason: missing token ‘content-type’ in CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Headers’ from CORS preflight channel).

[error display in firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afIKC.png)

So please give solution as soon as possible

Comment: would help if you added your code.

Comment: Please add your error message in text in your question, not as image. We currently cannot help with that error only, too. We need to have the relevant part of code (in the question, not as comment, use "edit" link), it seems to be related to `PerfectScrollbar`, do you use this function yourself in the code?

Comment: Yes i will add PerfectScrollbar function itself

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the CORS in the backened .  Please implement the CORS passthrough(since it is on local). If your backened is in spring framework then you can check here https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/